# Создать класс и методы в нем(ошибки в коде)

Tags: kotlin

Прошу Вас помочь с решением задачи. Система выдает, что программа выдает неверный ответ. Приложу задачу и свой код. Спасибо большое!

*Создайте класс для сахарного хранилища SugarStorage. Класс должен реализовывать следующие методы:
первичный конструктор, инициализирующий начальный баланс хранилища.
decreaseSugar(v:Int) - уменьшить баланс хранилища на v.
increaseSugar(v:Int) - увеличить баланс хранилища на v.
Также класс должен обладать публичным свойством volume:Int, задающим текущий баланс хранилища.
Обратите внимание, что
volume не может быть отрицательным. При попытке уменьшить баланс на величину, превышающую volume, значение volume должно становиться нулем.
decreaseSugar и increaseSugar должны игнорировать отрицательные аргументы.*

Мой код:

```
class SugarStorage (volume:Int = 10) {
   var volume : Int = 10
   fun decreaseSugar(v:Int) {
       if (volume < 0) {return}
       if (v > 0) {volume = volume - v}
   }
   fun increaseSugar(v:Int) {
       if (volume < 0) {return}
       if (v>0) {volume = volume + v}
   }
}
```

Comment: "При попытке уменьшить баланс на величину, превышающую volume, значение volume должно становиться нулем.", также бессмысленно проверять `volume < 0`, ведь написано, что "volume не может быть отрицательным"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SugarStorage (volume:Int = 10) {
    var volume : Int = 10
    fun decreaseSugar(v:Int) {
        if (v > 0) {
            volume -= v
        }
        if (volume < 0) {
            volume = 0
        }
    }
    fun increaseSugar(v:Int) {
        if (v > 0) {
            volume += v
        }
    }
}
```